# Backbone + React +Webpack Only setup without grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have made a chat app project using React and Backbone. But react components are not appearing in the browser. I know how to setup a webpack project for React. But here Im using Node to serve my app. Please can someone help me figure how to bring in Backbone and React together using Webpack only. I dont want to use Grunt for now. Please??

Comment: Interesting - why did you decide to use backbone AND react? I would recommend against that. There's ways to manage application state and asynchronous tasks such as api calls with things like Redux and Redux Saga

Comment: Yes. Im well aware of it. Just that I do not know how to use Redux for now. I wanted to use React's local state, but realize that I would definitely need Redux. Since I've learned it yet, I have decided to use Backbone Models in place of Reac't state. But now Im faced with a configuration problem. If you can help. Will be so glad